# Capping in topological cluster state error correction simulation

Tags: error-correction, topological-quantum-computing, cluster-states

In this paper: https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.90.052316, section IX., it is written:

"...The logical error rate (p_L) of a
given error model is determined by a continuous simulation
of an ever-growing topological cluster state. Each iteration
of the simulation extends the problem by t_check rounds. **The
problem is then capped by simulating two more rounds, with
all errors disabled, to ensure that all cells have been completed**.
The detection events are then analyzed to determine if a logical
error has occurred. Finally, the actions taken to cap the problem
are reversed in order to continue the simulation of the next t_check
rounds.

In more detail, each iteration begins with the simulation of
t_check rounds of the topological cluster state. **This is followed
by all errors being disabled and two more rounds of error
correction being performed to finalize any remaining cells**.
The value of t_check is dependent on the expected p_L, starting
at 1 when p_L is expected to be high (large p_comp and p_loss)
and up to 104 when p_L is expected to be low (small p_comp and
p_loss)..."

Can anyone help me understand the goal of the capping step? Is it essential to any error correction simulation? Why is it required to "ensure that all cells have been completed? Since in reality, we cannot perform such a step, will it give a valid logical error rate prediction?